# Cloud database or local database

Tags: database, cloud, clouddb

i want to implement web site with big database, its have about 5 million row for each table, and want to know that whats work is better for me, to have database in cloud  or have local database. does cloud db have ping problem?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a cloud database for a similar thing and it work very well.
i think there's no problem to use a cloud database.

Comment: which cloud db do you suggest me?